# Running XCode build.. takes a long time, how to see what´s happening

Tags: flutter, dart

my initial Build for iOS takes about 400+ seconds, Android around 20 seconds. During that time, vscode output tab only shows "Running Xcode build..". Is there a way to know what´s going on?
I already tried to build with --verbose, but that seems to not what I wanted.

P.S.: I know there is a known problem with firebase cloud_store which slows builds down, however Im not using this package, if at all relating, we use firebase_messaging.

Answer (score 2):

You can try building the app with Xcode itself. Open the `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` file with Xcode, assign a development team if necessary then try building the app within Xcode, you will be able to keep track of the log and see all the warnings/ errors.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode then clean and build the project and try to re-run. This works for me. I was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running flutter in verbose mode with -v option. If that doesn’t help try re-running Xcode build command manually with verbose option.

See more: https://dartcode.org/docs/running-flutter-in-verbose-mode/